# Images failed to load in nitrous rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nitrousio

Hi all I have just started making my own website and I am trying to develop and deploy in Ruby on Rails on Nitrous. 
However, when I run `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and look at the preview page, the html loads but the assets, ie images, do not load. 
Can anyone shed some light on this?
[image]

Comment: Are there anything in the browser console? Are there any errors in rails console?

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev nope there isn't... :(

Comment: It's really hard to say what exactly wrong without any extra debug information